# fancyalert in typescript nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I want to use FancyAlert on nativescript typescript but when tried to import using this
 `import { TNSFancyAlert, TNSFancyAlertButton } from "nativescript-fancyalert";`. But it doesn't work. Im using Nativescript Sidekick and when I add that line of FancyAlert, i'm not able to build it. Is there any other way or alternative for FancyAlert? or maybe a solution for this on how to make this one work on typescript.

Here's the exact error i'm facing

[image: TS2305 Error]

Comment: Please add more details to your question, you must at least explain what you mean by "it doesn't work", whether it's a error / what you see in console?

Comment: Is there no errors in console?

Comment: just try to import import { TNSFancyAlert} from "nativescript-fancyalert"; only and don't import 'TNSFancyAlertButton ' just to check if it compiles. There is problem with export of TNSFancyAlertButton

Answer (score 1):

You need to import that.
NativeScript 4x

```
tns plugin add nativescript-fancyalert
```

NativeScript 3x and older

```
tns plugin add nativescript-fancyalert@1.2.0
```

Make sure to clean build by
tns platform remove android
otherwise you may counter problem that says

```
PromptDialog is not a constructor
```

and in your .ts file

```
import { TNSFancyAlert } from "nativescript-fancyalert";
```

Comment: I did import that plugin. The problem it is not recognized. I can't compile it.

Comment: Im having TS2305 error. Im using nativescript typescript

Answer (score 1):

The type declaration file bundled with `nativescript-fancyalert` is broken: it is trying to export `TNSFancyAlertButton` from the `common` module, but that doesn't work in the compiled NPM package because only a `common.js` file is provided and there is no `common.d.ts`.  I suggest you [file an issue](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert) and let upstream decide how to fix it.  As a workaround, you can add the following module augmentation to the file that imports `nativescript-fancyalert`:

```
declare module "nativescript-fancyalert" { 
    export class TNSFancyAlertButton {
        public label: string;
        public action: Function;
        constructor(model?: any);
    }
}
```